# How to check if an object contain a property in dart

Tags: dart

Coming from JavaScript world I would do something like this `(propertyName in object)` to check if a property exist inside an object. can someone share an easy way to do the same thing in dart.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that directly<sup>1</sup>.

What you should do is figure out *why* the object should have a property of that name, which means *which interface* the object implements which provides that property.
So, if you think an object might implement `Iterable` and therefore have a `length` property, you check:

```dart
if (o is Iterable) {
  var length = o.length;
}
```

<sup>1</sup>: Except using `dart:mirrors`, which is doesn't work on most platforms. If you can use mirrors, then you can do:

```dart
var result; 
try { 
  result = reflect(o).getField(#property);
} catch (e) { 
  /* nope */ 
}
```